# User-based media gallery

Tags: buddypress, gallery

I'm building a site that uses both WordPress and BuddyPress and I'm looking to build a custom section whereby the user can upload work and people can comment/rate it. I've browsed around at various different options but it would seem using a custom post type like and then allowing members to submit content would be the best option.

Is their a better way to do this? Or do you think post types are the best option. To get an idea of the kind of functionality it will require: http://dribbble.com/

The idea will be to have images as URLs like domain.com/designs/my-awesome-work-2201/

And when viewing member profiles you will be able to view their latest work etc, so they need to be linked up with a user and not just floating randomly in the database. Not sure how easy this will be to do with normal users who are not authors/editors.

Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Anyone got any feedback? thanks

Comment: Anyone got any feedback? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom post types seem the best match for what you want: you get the permalinks, comments, ... You only need one of the many rating plugins as an extra.

If the users have accounts you could try making them authors, it could work since they exist in the `users` table so the `posts` table can link there. You know you can create [a limited role that can only access one specific custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/can-i-make-user-role-that-can-only-access-a-certian-content-type), and not edit everything? Otherwise do it as a custom taxonomy: this also gives you automatic permalinks and archive pages.

Comment: Sounds awesome. But could you show to set this up with a post type or point to some tutorial/code as I haven't a clue how to do that bit. I can set up a post type fine just not sticking it with a custom role.

Comment: @Cameron: It seems to be [easy to do with the Members plugin](http://webtide.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/how-to-use-the-members-plugin-to-restrict-access-to-wordpress-3-0-custom-post-type/), but you can also do it without the plugin if you write all the code to create the roles and capabilities yourself.

Comment: The Role Scoper plugin (http://agapetry.net/news/introducing-role-scoper/) is great for managing very specific roles and capabilities too. One aspect that might be useful is being able to lock access to images in the Media Library to only those uploaded by each user.

Comment: @Rick: Interesting, maybe you should also put it as an answer on [this question specifically about limiting user access to the media library](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded)?

Comment: Sure, will do :)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm...

1 - You could use a custom field

2 - When the user is uploading content, you ask them to enter their name, create a folder for them on your server, once the name is taken - users will be prompted again - you can show the user work based on the folder structure and such for the whole gallery

I don't think you will find a plugin that will do this for you - you will have to do customized coding - can you state what are the reasons stopping you from using Authors/editors option - if it is because users are too lazy to sign up, maybe you can use some open id model instead.

Comment: Users will have accounts. But they will be just members and not authors/editors and so will not have access to the back-end /wp-admin/

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the PhotoSmash Galleries plugin (available on Wordpress.org).  It allows you to create Galleries that users can upload images to.  It also has an optional star rating system.

You can use custom layouts to display your images in galleries however you like.  They're pretty easy to create using standard HTML/CSS/Javascript + PhotoSmash field tags (like [thumb] to show the thumbnail or [caption] to show Captions.

You can create custom forms with custom fields, so you can pretty much get whatever info you want from your user and display it in galleries.  It doesn't provide multi-image uploading, which is a common request.

You can set the minimum role for uploading by gallery (right down to anonymous).

You can also show galleries containing a specific contributor's images as well.

There is also an extension plugin that creates new Posts on upload of images where you could have comments, etc.

Unfortunately, it does not have Commenting functionality within the galleries themselves, though this has been a commonly requested feature.