# Can I make user role that can only access a certian content type?

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities, user-roles

I would like make a custom role that can only access a custom content type that I'm going to be creating in the admin.   Is that possible and does any know of any examples or tutorias that I should check out to get started?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has a `capabilities` (or simple version: `capability_type`) that you can use to specify a separate capability to create and edit posts of this type. If you set this, you can create [a new role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that has the capability to edit these custom posts, but not regular posts.