# Media library to list images only user uploaded

Tags: media, media-library, pre-get-posts

I want to list images for only user uploaded image. Here is the scenario:

1. Using the image uploader on front end using iframe.
2. I have added `upload_files` cap to subscriber level users and want them to see only images they uploaded.
3. I've found this Q [Restricting users to view only media library items they have uploaded?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded) but the accepted answer not working for me.

   ```
   // Code originally by @t31os
   add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');

   function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) 
   {
       global $current_user, $pagenow;

       if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
           return;

       if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
           return;

       if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
           $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );

       return;
   }
   ```
4. The frontend page i am using the image uploader is named "Entry".
5. If i remove this part of the code `if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow ) return;` the code works. I i think i have to improve that part of the conditional code but could not figure it out. The conditional is important because i don't want the code to apply on other pages where it not required.

So, i need help to improve the conditional part as i mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: If you're copy/pasting code, please do the following: If you only wrapped your code in a function name, please add the proper amount of spaces so `function` doesn't align with the fn content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media upload form that i was pulling up via thickbox was `media-upload.php`. So, i had to change the conditional to `if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow && 'media-upload.php' != $pagenow)`. I forgot to look into the obvious place :)

```
// Code originally by @t31os
add_action('pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments');

function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) 
{
    global $current_user, $pagenow;

    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    if( 'upload.php' != $pagenow && 'media-upload.php' != $pagenow)
        return;

    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
        $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me in order to list the items uploaded by a user on the media library.

```
function users_my_media_only( $wp_query ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/upload.php' ) ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user = $current_user->ID;
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
            global $current_user;
            $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
        }
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'users_my_media_only' );
```

It will allow all users with the `manage_options` capability (usually admin) to see all images, the other users will see only their own images. Note that a few improvements can be made like `$pagenow` and `current_user_can`. Not a beauty but it does the job

Comment: Ideally you'd try to compare to some part of the [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) result.