# WP Query Obj: Set value to be unequal | Hide media by admin

Tags: wp-query, uploads, media-library, exclude

I would like to hide all media uploaded by the admin.

I've found an answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded) to be pretty close. Except that the query returns all media uploaded by a specific (current) user, instead of excluding all by a specific user.

```
[...]
if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') )
    $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->id );
[...]
```

Q: Is it possible to modify the wp_query_obj to exclude all posts by a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is similar, just exclude the author by prefixing the id with a minus sign:

```
$wp_query_obj->set( 'author', '-1' );
```

See [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for a full list of query arguments.