# Conditional tag to determine if the user is viewing the Add Media (after clicking Add media button)

Tags: media-library, conditional-tags

Is there a WordPress conditional tag for checking if the user is viewing the add media popup after clicking the Add media button? If none, is there an alternative function that can be used?
  Thanks for any tips and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple actions available. Demo:

```
add_action( 'upload_ui_over_quota', 'wpse_78085_callback' );
add_action( 'pre-upload-ui', 'wpse_78085_callback' );
add_action( 'pre-plupload-upload-ui', 'wpse_78085_callback' );
add_action( 'post-plupload-upload-ui', 'wpse_78085_callback' );
add_action( 'post-upload-ui', 'wpse_78085_callback' );


function wpse_78085_callback()
{
    # see wp-includes/media-template.php
    print '<pre>' . current_filter() . '</pre>';
}
```

Result:

[image]