# Restrict Contributors to view only their own custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

For our 'Posts' type, our Contributors can see only their own posts, which is what we want. But for our custom post types, Contributors can see every post, including drafts. Is there a way to limit their view of custom posts so they only see their own posts like it is in the 'Posts' type?

Edit:
Maybe I wasn't as clear about my problem. I want the Contributors to be able to see all of the custom types (Videos, Images, etc), but within each custom type I want them to be able to see only their own posts. So if they look at the CPT Videos, for example, they would only be able to see their own posted videos, not a post by someone else.

Comment: There are solutions about that here, have you searched? It's always nice to reserch before asking, and include any relevant info in the Question. Check this guide: [ask].

Comment: I did search before I asked, but I didn't see anything that dealt with my problem. Most were about blocking custom posts from being shown altogether to lower roles, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the action hook [**`pre_get_posts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

See the comments for details and modify the Custom Post Type(s) to your own:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_cpt_listing_by_author_wpse_89233' );

function filter_cpt_listing_by_author_wpse_89233( $wp_query_obj ) 
{
    // Front end, do nothing
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    global $current_user, $pagenow;
    wp_get_current_user();

    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php
    if( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User') )
        return;

    // Not the correct screen, bail out
    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow )
        return;

    // Not the correct post type, bail out
    if( 'portfolio' != $wp_query_obj->query['post_type'] )
        return;
        
    // If the user is not administrator, filter the post listing
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        $wp_query_obj->set('author', $current_user->ID );
}
```

You'll notice that the post count <kbd>All|Published|Drafts</kbd> needs to be corrected.
See the [solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34858/12615).

Comment: With the current Wordpress version > 4.5 you should use: wp_get_current_user() instead get_currentuserinfo() (which has been deprecated) - no other changes are needed.