# Exclude some photos in media library

Tags: uploads, media-library

I was searching for filters to exclude some photos from media library.

I have an array of image ID, and want them to exclude from media library any idea?

Comment: `pre_get_posts` filter with `post__not_in` parameter, targeting media library query - quickly outlined draft of an idea

Comment: My pleasure! You will find additional information on this [Q&A's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded).