# How to hide posts count and posts of other users from edit.php for contributors and authors

Tags: author

I am using wordpress latest version and running a multi author blog. When any user (contributor or author) go to edit.php, they are seeing posts and post counts of other users. I hide the posts of other authors by this code,

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $user_level;
```

```
if($query->is_admin && $user_level < 5) {
    global $user_ID;
    $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
    unset($user_ID);
}
unset($user_level);

return $query;
```

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');

Now they are not seeing other posts but seeing total post counts and published posts count. See screenshot:

[image: editor.php screen of contributors]

I wan't to hide all and published section from users edit.php and other section will count only own posts. Please help me to do this!

Comment: @CarlosCosta If you  have a question, please post it as one, referring if necessary to this one.

Comment: I found this answer solved the problem of updating the post count to exclude other authors' posts -  it might help anyone else who has this problem too:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178236/correct-post-count-all-published-drafts-pending-trash-for-custom-pos

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a specific All() and Pubished() post counts from Posts-editor page you can:

```
// Create a specific hook
add_filter("views_edit-post", 'custom_editor_counts', 10, 1);


function custom_editor_counts($views) {
    // var_dump($views) to check other array elements that you can hide.
    unset($views['all']);
    unset($views['publish']);
    return $views;
}
```

Lets go more advanced and remove All() from Posts-editor admin table and Published() from Pages-editor admin table.

```
// Create a hook per specific Admin Editor Table-view inside loop
foreach( array( 'edit-post', 'edit-page') as $hook )
    add_filter( "views_$hook" , 'custom_editor_counts', 10, 1);


function custom_editor_counts($views) {

    // Get current admin page view from global variable 
    global $current_screen;

    // Remove count-tab per specific screen viewed.
    switch ($current_screen->id) {
        case 'edit-post':
            unset($views['all']);
            break;
        case 'edit-page':
            unset($views['publish']);
            break;
    }

    return $views;
}
```

Refferences:
[[Hide the post count behind Post Views (Remove All, Published and Trashed) in Custom Post Type]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149143/hide-the-post-count-behind-post-views-remove-all-published-and-trashed-in-cus)

**UPDATE**

Updated an answer with a code how to update posts count for specific user, excluding "all" and "publish" views. Recently tested on WP 4.3 twentyfifteen.

```
add_filter("views_edit-post", 'custom_editor_counts', 10, 1);

function custom_editor_counts($views) {
    $iCurrentUserID = get_current_user_id();

    if ($iCurrentUserID !== 0) {

        global $wpdb;

        foreach ($views as $index => $view) {
            if (in_array($index, array('all', 'publish')))
                continue;
            $viewValue = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_author=$iCurrentUserID AND post_status='$index'");
            $views[$index] = preg_replace('/\(.+\)/U', '(' . $viewValue . ')', $views[$index]);
        }

        unset($views['all']);
        unset($views['publish']);
    }
    return $views;
}
```

Comment: can't update count. [http://i.imgur.com/3miD9Es.jpg] There seeing draft 1 but there is no post in draft for this author. Tell me brief please.

Comment: Please check anwser updated