# How do I remove All and Published if not admin?

Tags: admin

Is it possible to Remove those menu items for a Post and a Custom Post Type page ?
thank you

[image]

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', function( $views )
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return $views;

    $remove_views = [ 'all','publish','future','sticky','draft','pending','trash' ];

foreach( (array) $remove_views as $view )
{
    if( isset( $views[$view] ) )
        unset( $views[$view] );
}
return $views;
} );


/**
 * Force the 'mine' view on the 'edit-post' screen
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( 
           is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
        && 'edit-post' === get_current_screen()->id 
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
    )
        $q->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() ); 
} );'
```

This code comes from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/224253/26350).

This is working great for posts.  But I can't wrap my head around using it for a custom post type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide posts count and posts of other users from edit.php for contributors and authors](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199796/how-to-hide-posts-count-and-posts-of-other-users-from-edit-php-for-contributors)

Comment: Thank you Charles, I tried to do my due diligence. I have working code for the "posts page"  However I can't code it correct to work with a custom post type. Replace -> 'views_edit-post' with a custom post type.

Comment: @Charles after he added some code, I think his question is how to implement  `views_edit-{$post_type}`, as Peter says, he's managed it for `posts`.

Answer (score 1):

### responding to code added by OP

replace `post` with the slug of your post type.

`add_filter('views_edit-SLUG_OF_YOUR_POST_TYPE', function($views) { ...`

So a custom post type of Library Books with a slug of `library-books`:

`add_filter('views_edit-library-books', function($views) {...`

### original response

Use [`$wp_roles->remove_cap( $role, $cap );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap) on all roles except the admin, removing the `edit_others_posts` cap.
[See this for caps and roles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  I have it working now for "posts".  with the code a pasted above.  I can't wrap my head around a custom post type to replace 'views_edit-post'

Comment: i've updated the answer with an example

Comment: @PeterB please mark the answer accepted to close the question thanks. You need to register for that.