# How to do logical OR in terms in WP Query?

Tags: wp-query

I have a code that hides images of other users. But I need to make sure that users can see their images OR images from categories.

```
function my_files_only( $wp_query ) {

    if ( ! $_POST["action"] == "attachment" )
    {
            return;
    }

    if ( current_user_can( 'image_verified' ) )
    {
            return;
    }

    global $current_user;
    $wp_query->set( 'author', "$current_user->id"); }
    add_filter('parse_query', 'my_files_only' );
```

You can also add: $wp_query->set( 'mlo-category', "license");

But then the selection logic will be equal to AND. Therefore, we need to prescribe: relation OR.
How can I fit such a request in my code?

Comment: Just so I got it right, you want a query that does author = current_user *OR* mlo-category = "license" ?

Comment: Yes, it's right!

Answer (score 1):

As WP_Query doesn't natively allow you to do logical OR operations (except on meta values), one option is just to run two queries to get all the Post ID's, then pass those to a new WP_Query which you can use for a loop. This is quite long and requires 3 queries, so perhaps someone will know a shorter solution

This code taken from an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984797/wordpress-wp-query-with-operator-in-meta-query-not-working-how-to-combine-que), and untested. You may have to tweak it for your use case, in particular I'm not sure what 'mlo-category' is, so you may need to convert that to a better [WP_Query parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

```
    $postsCurrentUser = get_posts(array(
        'author', "$current_user->id"); 
        ));
        
    $postsCategory = get_posts(array(
        'mlo-category', "license"
        ));

    $mergedPosts = array_merge( $postsCurrentUser, $postsCategory ); //combine queries

    $postIds = array();

    // Find any post ID that is in one array or the other, don't include any twice
    foreach( $mergedPosts as $item ) {
        if (!in_array($item->ID, $postIds)) {
            $postIds[]=$item->ID;
        }
    }

    $args = array('post__in' => $postIds);

    $q = WP_Query($args);
```

Let me know if that does what you want

Comment: Good afternoon! I tried your code, but realized that I formed the question a little incorrectly. I need to apply this code in the hook when requesting to display media files.

Comment: Example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/restricting-users-to-view-only-media-library-items-they-have-uploaded/132319